# Checking if CSS properties are supported

Tags: javascript, css, feature-detection

I'm trying to avoid Modernizr because it's huge, and I've seen that most people use code like this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
if(div.style['transform'])...
```

But is it really necessary to create a new element on which to test the properties on, or can I just use the "document.documentElement.style" object?

```
var s = document.documentElement.style;
if('transform' in s)...
```

it's shorter when I have to test for multiple properties. But I don't know if it will work on browsers that I cannot test it on.

Comment: My *uncompressed* modernizr.js file is 10K, and it gzips down to 4K.

Comment: yes but that's still a lot more than just a few bytes. And it's not like the support code will ever change because it targets old browser

Comment: It's a matter of proportion. Most of your images will be bigger than 4k heck even10k. Modernizer works and is *tiny* compared to most other things in comparison....but it's your decision.

Comment: but I don't use images anymore, they don't scale nicely. Let's say that the 10x feature detection code size gain is not important, then what benefits does Modernizr have over my code?

Comment: Why not build a custom Modernizr, and only include the tests you need rather than taking ALL the tests?  I just grabbed 10 random tests and my version of Modernizr was 3.12k.

To answer the question in your previous comment, the benefit is to not reinvent the wheel and stand on the shoulders of giants who have nailed these tests.